# Why am i using support.v4 package when I am using Android v 17?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I think I'm missing something, but don't really understand the reasoning behind the support packages for objects like ViewPager and Fragment etc and how do I know which one to use?

I'm writing an app with min sdk 16, why are the objects not included somewhere in the API without the "support.v4" (some appear to be support v.13) qualification?

Can somebody shed a bit of light?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The support library is for the following reason:

- for backwards compatibility
- for functionality that is not included in the standard SDK's such as `ViewPager`

Here, `ViewPager` isn't included in the standard SDK. So, if you want to use `Viewpager` API then you have to use support library.

`Fragment` in the support library is mainly for backwards compatibility. If you are implementing something using support library which required to use `Fragment` then you will need to use `Fragment` from support library.